# python twisted environment: _Cryptography_cffi_444d7397xa22f8491.pyd DLL load failed?

Tags: python, twisted, setuptools, python-cffi

my develop environment:
win7 64
python2.7.6 64
twisted 13.2

I have installed all modules twisted required.
but always throw an error:

```
    from twisted.internet import reactor 
cffi.ffiplatform.VerificationError: importing 'D:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\cryptography\\_Cryptography_cffi_444d7397xa22f8491.pyd': DLL load failed:
```

in another computer,I can use default reactor,but the error appeared when I used iocpreactor.and when use the default reactor,tcp mode,only one connection will work fine...

i have tried to change some old versions of modules,the problem remained the same 
what's wrong?

Comment: It looks like you're missing some information that came after the `DLL load failed:` message.  Also, when diagnosing this kind of problem, it's important to provide as much information as possible.  What exact version of `cffi`, what exact version of `cryptography`, did you build Python yourself or did you download it from python.org, what C compiler are you using, do you have a C compiler, and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

This error is likely because you have not installed 64-bit OpenSSL. It is available as a binary from http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html. Just download the Win64 version and install with the default settings.

This issue has been added to the cryptography.io [FAQ](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/faq/#when-i-try-to-use-cryptography-on-windows-i-get-a-cffi-ffiplatform-verificationerror).

Answer (score 0):

thanks so much,I have fixed the problem.u are right.

I installed the pyopenssl by pip at the beginning, and I also tried to download the pyopenssl.egg.
at the last I found a .exe file to install.then twisted did not require pycrypto.the problem fixed

maybe there's some  compiling problems when installing the .egg version